# Trying to Create the Server Socket On the Port [ 8443] With the Message: Couldn't Find a Self-Signed Certificate in Chai

Tags: tibco

Dear Greetings I try to deploy new Archive in my server; the Archive incloud web service use HTTPS and I use port 8443 because I already used 443 for another Archive. The web serive it's working in TIBCO Designer, but when I try to deploy it returns below error: BW-EXT-LOG-100000 Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"] java.io.IOException: An AXSecurityException was thrown while trying to create the server socket on the port [ 8443] with the message: couldn't find a self-signed certificate in chain Could you please advise me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in  new Archive there is one process connect to 443 ,change all process to connect to 8443